# Ruby debugger: "INTERNAL ERROR!!! undefined method `skip_next_exception' for Debugger:Module" (OSX 10.7 Lion)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, osx-lion, sinatra

Using the [debugger](http://rubygems.org/gems/debugger) gem, I get the following error when attempting to use the 'skip' command:

> INTERNAL ERROR!!! undefined method `skip_next_exception' for
>   Debugger:Module

- Ruby Version: 1.9.3-p194
- RubyGems Version: 1.8.24
- OS: OSX 10.7 Lion

Is this a bug in the debugger or simply user error?

Comment: Are you using a [supported Ruby](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger-ruby_core_source/tree/master/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source) and done any [troubleshooting](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/wiki/Troubleshooting)?

Comment: Yes, versions of Rubies, gems, and possibly OS would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your code. But I can suggest the following solutions:

1. Make sure you add `debbugger` gem to your Gemfile or `require 'debbugger'` it directly
2. [Add](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers) gem's helpers in sinatra application. This is crucial.
3. Try to use gem functionality outside Sinatra to check if it works or not